# Update values used in array based on update in store (svelte)?

Tags: javascript, svelte

In a nutshell, I am building a web app like mycolor.space, where you type in the hex value of a color and the application spits out a bunch of color palettes using a library called tinycolor, which does some simple lightening/darkening/rotation of hues.

So I'm able to do handle all the binding and subscriptions to the store value that we'll call `primaryColor`. `primaryColor` successfully updates when the user types in a hex code into an input field. I have a svelte component called `Palettes.svelte` which looks something like this:

```
<script>
import tiny color from 'tinycolor2'

export let color

const palettes = [
  {
    name: 'Simple Gradient',
    colors: [
      tinycolor(color).colorMutationFunction1(),
      tinycolor(color).colorMutationFunction2(),
      .
      .
      .
      ]
  },
  .
  .
  .

]
</script>
<main>
  <h1>{color}</h1>
  {#each palettes as palette}
    {#each palette.colors as color}
      <div>{color}</div>
    {/each}
  {/each}
</main>
```

So the core functionality is there. It produces color palettes based on the initial store value, which lives inside the array from the getgo. The problem is that the value `color` inside of the `palettes` array does not update reactively when the user changes the hex color value in the input. The `h1` tag in the main body of this component predictably *does* update alongside the store. I have read here and there that in order to iteratively change array values based on a change in the state of a store variable in svelte that you have to do some weird syntax that sets the array to itself, like `palettes = palettes`. However, I have only ever seen this in the context of a function.

Please let me know if any more information would be of any insight. The rest of my app is updating and passing the store variable just fine, so I know I'm just missing something fundamental about how to handle this.

Comment: Here's a Svelte tutorial on [reactive declarations](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations) and a section in the docs [$: marks a statement as reactive](https://svelte.dev/docs#3_$_marks_a_statement_as_reactive)

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you have to explicitly mark `palettes` as *reactive*, this means that it will be recalculated if the values it is based on change.

The general syntax for this is `$: a = b` where `a` will always update whenever `b` (or anything else on the *righthand side* of the equation) changes.

In your case the syntax would become:

```js
$: palettes = [
  {
    name: 'Simple Gradient',
    colors: [
      tinycolor(color).colorMutationFunction1(),
      tinycolor(color).colorMutationFunction2(),
  }
]
```

Since `color` appears on the right hand, `palettes` will be recalculated when the color changes.